# countdown kick start wrong answer

Tags: c

i was trying this kick start question, the test give the right answer yet when submitting attempt it says wrong answer, it's second question i'm doing and not sure how this really works here's my code :
function :

```
int num_subarray (int array[], int array_size, int k) {

    int     sum = 0, j = 1, i;
    for (i = array_size - 1; 0 <= i; i--) {
        if (array[i] == j) j++;
        else j = 1;
        if (j == k) {
            sum++;
            j = 1;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

here's the main :

```
int main () {
    int     t, n, k, array[N], i, j = 1;

    scanf ("%d", &t);
    do {
        scanf ("%d%d", &n, &k);
        i = 0;
        do {
            scanf ("%d", &array[i]);
            i++;
        } while (i < n);
        printf ("\n Case #%d: %d", j, num_subarray (array, n, k));
        j++;
    } while (j <= t);


    return 0;
}
```

here's the question :
[Countdown - Kick Start](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/000000000019ff43/00000000003380d2)

Comment: "the test give the right answer". Did you test with more than just the sample test input?

Comment: no, i can't think of any @kaylum

Comment: I don't think you are interpreting `k` correctly. When it says find a `k-countdown` if `k=3`, that mean `3, 2, 1` by my reading, otherwise the example with `101 100 99 98` should contain three 2-countdowns (e.g. `101, 100` and `100, 99` and `99, 98`)... but instead contains zero 2-countdowns.

Comment: Also, you need a `#define N 200000` that will cause StackOverflow on some compilers -- why not just make `array` global (or `static`) and avoid the issue?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin could you elaborate what you think is wrong? The comparison is done from the right, looking for a series `1, 2, ..., k` which seems not too bad.

Comment: Are you sure there has to be a space in front of each line? How strict do they compare the output? Does whitespace matter?

Comment: @Gerhardh i've changed that and it's not the whitespace  :(

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin i think that's the reason thank you

Comment: Sure your `num_subarray` function you need to loop over `n` elements, keeping simple counter that also serves as a flag indicating when you are `in` a kcountdown. You basically loop and check `if (arr[i] == k) in = 1;` to indicate the start of a kcountdown. You have another check of `if (in) {` and check `if (arr[i] + 1 == arr[i-1])  /* current is 1 less than last */ { in++; if (in == k)  /* full sequence */ { sum++; in = 0; } } else /* sequence failed */ { in = 0 } `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from my comments, at least from my reading of the question, a *k-countdown* actually starts with `'k'` and counts down to `1`, so in the example a *3-countdown* is `3, 2, 1` a *6-countdown* is `6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1`, etc...

You are also given limits on the array size of `2x10^5` (200000). The consideration there is that on some compilers 200000 4-byte `int` values will exceed the default stack size, so you may as well make `array` a global or `static` to avoid that issue altogether.

Another check you will want to impose is on the read of the values from the file. You will have `k` at that point and for there to be a *k-countdown*, the input must contain `k` and it must be at an index of `i < n - k` in order for there to be enough elements left in that array to hold a *k-countdown*. so if you are given `k = 10` in a 10-element input, if the 1st element isn't `10` -- that array can't hold a *k-countdown* (that implementation is left to you -- but if you are failing a large check -- I would suspect that as one of the probable causes)

Putting that together and using the function name `kcountdowns` instead of your `num_subarray` and using `kcd` as your `sum`, a quick attempt could look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NMAX 200000

int arr[NMAX];      /* global storage for array, up to 2x10^5 elements */

/** function to compute no. of kcountdowns in n elements of arr */
int kcountdowns (int n, int k)
{
    int i = 0,      /* array index */
        in = 0,     /* flag & counter in(true)/out(false) of a kcountdown */
        kcd = 0;    /* number of kcountdowns found */

    do {                                    /* loop over all elements */
        if (in) {                           /* if in a kcountdown */
            if (arr[i] + 1 == arr[i-1]) {   /* check current is 1 less than last */
                in++;                       /* increment in flag/count */
                if (in == k) {              /* full sequence found */
                    kcd += 1;               /* add a kcountdown to sum */ 
                    in = 0;                 /* reset in 0/false */
                }
            }
            else                            /* otherwise set flag false */
                in = 0;
        }
        if (arr[i] == k)        /* if k found, set in to 1-true */
            in = 1;
    } while (++i < n);

    return kcd;     /* return number of kcountdows found */
}
```

(**note:** the use of the global `arr`. Generally the use of global variables is discouraged, but here with the potential stack size issue, using a global or making the array `static` are two reasonable options)

A quick `main()` that leaves the input check to you to implement could be:

```
int main (void) {

    int t;

    if (scanf ("%d", &t) != 1 || t < 1 || 100 < t)          /* read/validate t */
        return 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {   /* loop over each case */
        int n, k;
        if (scanf ("%d %d", &n, &k) != 2 || n < 2 || n < k) /* read/validate n & k */
            return 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)             /* loop reading/validating elements */
            if (scanf ("%d", &arr[j]) != 1)
                return 1;
        printf ("Case #%d: %d\n", i + 1, kcountdowns (n, k));   /* output result */
    }
```

(**note:** you would normally want to read each line into a buffer so you can enforce a validation of only reading a single line of input for the array values. Reading with `scanf` -- it will happily ignore a `'\n'` and start reading the next testcase if there is a defect in the input file)

At least with the input given, the results match all testcases, e.g.

**Example Test Input**

```
3
12 3
1 2 3 7 9 3 2 1 8 3 2 1
4 2
101 100 99 98
9 6
100 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 100
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/kcountdown <dat/kcountdown.txt
Case #1: 2
Case #2: 0
Case #3: 1
```

error check:

```
$ echo $?
0
```

Let me know if you have further questions.